# Python Devtools blocks selenium click()

Tags: python, selenium, chromium, devtools

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6APO.png)

So basically I can't click an element this thing pops up
I'm using developer tools for mobile emulation in selenium

**script will stop functioning (semi-crash)** even though i close this popup manually it wont fix

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]').click()
```

I've Tried send_keys(Keys.RIGHT) or enter, headless mode and ...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, so you want to click that black circle button, but that context menu appears? am I correct?

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera yes, the click function wont work at all, I've tried other elements, switching windows, headless option and ... but it just won't work

Comment: Just try if manually also that pop-up comes, after clicking that button. Or else give it a try with actions double click method.

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera I'm assuming that Devtools or mobile mode is making elements unclickable, the thing is program will stop functioning even though i manually close the pop-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the touch function in **Chrome developer tools Device emulator** was blocking the **selenium** clicks by popping an alert up !

 Solution: Change your emulated device to **no-touch** mode

 Open developer-tools(F12) and then click on cell Phone icon(CTRL+SHIFT+M), on emulator panel click those 3 dots and enable **Device Type** now change the it from **mobile** to **mobile(no touch)**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU05E.png)

Comment: Please answer with more than a link, if it ever dies, this answer becomes useless